# converting array type string to double with .csv read

Tags: c++, arrays, csv

I am taking in a .csv file that contains strings and converting everything within a certain range to type double. My goal is really just to capture the 4th column, but taking it all in as a matrix seems to be the best method in case I want to capture more. However, when I convert from string to type double, the conversions don't make sense to me.

A string that says "24 Month" will get converted to the value 24. However, a string that says "4.35183217" will get converted to 0 (really it's some very small negative number). Why is this?

[see input here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bF1mI.jpg)
[see output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsVvy.jpg)

```
double data[38][27];
std::ifstream file("YC Rate Levels.csv");

for (int row = 0; row < 38; ++row)
{
    std::string line;
    std::getline(file, line);
    if (!file.good())
        break;

    std::stringstream iss(line);

    for (int col = 0; col < 27; ++col)
    {
        std::string val;
        std::getline(iss, val, ',');
        if (!iss.good())
            break;

        std::stringstream convertor(val);
        convertor >> data[row][col];
    }
}

std::cout << "Col 3" << " - " << "Col 4" << std::endl;;
for (int i = 0; i < 38; ++i)
{
    std::cout << data[i][3] << " - " << data[i][4] << std::endl;
}

std::cin.clear(); // reset any error flags
std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n'); // ignore any characters in the input buffer until we find an enter character
std::cin.get(); // get one more char from the user

return 0;
```

Comment: I don't think you want to be using `>>` to feed `"24 Month"` into a double field. That string isn't convertible into a double.

Comment: I agree. I'm not expecting everything to be converted properly. But the fields which are clearly double aren't converting from string to double.

Comment: How confident are you that the string is actually being read in? Have you stepped through this with a debugger and verified that the string is getting written to `val`? By not initializing `data`, you risk that you could be printing junk in uninitialized memory without knowing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is uninitialized and undefined, that's why it defaults to some small numbers. You can initialize as follows: `double data[38][27]={0};` or better yet use `std::vector`

Secondly, your *.csv file is something like this:

```
"abc", "123", "345"
```

There is an extra blank space or quotation mark. The string representation is `"\"345\""` and is not converted to `345.00`.

Instead of `stringstream`, use `std::stod` which throws an exception when the input cannot be converted. Example:

```
try 
{
    double temp = std::stod(val);
}
catch (...)
{
    std::cout << "bad input: " << val << std::endl;
}
```

Use the function below to remove quotation marks and blank spaces from left/right of text:

```
void trim(std::string& s, const char* t)
{
    s.erase(0, s.find_first_not_of(t));
    s.erase(s.find_last_not_of(t) + 1);
}
```

Putting it together:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> data;

std::string line;
while(std::getline(file, line))
{
    std::vector<double> row;
    std::stringstream iss(line);

    std::string val;
    while (std::getline(iss, val, ','))
    {
        trim(val, " \"");
        try 
        {
            double temp = std::stod(val);
            row.push_back(temp);
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            std::cout << "bad input: " << val << std::endl;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    data.push_back(row);
}

for (const auto &row : data)
{
    for (const auto &col : row)
        std::cout << col << ", ";
    std::cout << "\n";
    //if (data[i].size() > 4) std::cout << data[i][4] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried initializing with the array = {0}, but now it just gives me zero. I'll go through what you said and see where I can get with that. Thanks.

Comment: I actually just figured it out. The issue was with the if (!iss.good()  break;     why this is... i have no idea! but for some reason it viewed that string of numbers as bad and broke to the next line.